# Program is not compiling for Java what am I Missing

Tags: java, netbeans

```
package freshjuice;


class FreshJuice {

    enum FreshJuiceSize { SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE }
        FreshJuiceSize size;
    }


}

public class FreshJuiceTest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FreshJuice juice = new FreshJuice();
        juice.size = FreshJuice.FreshJuiceSize.MEDIUM ;
        System.out.println("Size: " + juice.size);
        // TODO code application logic here
    }

}
```

This is the error message I am getting:

```
Error: Main method not found in class freshjuice.FreshJuice, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
C:\Users\TheGODMasterDu\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your file must be called `FreshJuiceTest.java`, because that is the class where your main method is located.

Answer (score 0):

Your file name is `FreshJuice.java` which does not contains `main()`
In short netbeans looking for `main()` in your first class

Either change your file name to `FreshJuiceTest.java` or swap the code of your classes and define `FreshJuice.java` as `public` and remove `public` from second class